# Opening .bat file in CMDER instead of default CMD

Tags: batch-file, cmd.exe, console, terminal-emulator, cmder

I want to associate `.bat` files with another console emulator, named cmder, so that when they are opened they must start up with my preferred program.

How to do this?

ps: I'm using windows 10.

Comment: update `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\batfile\shell\open\command`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cmder which is in fact preconfigured ConEmu, do not support [Default terminal](http://conemu.github.io/en/DefaultTerminal.html) feature properly.

So, you may either use (and configure) bare ConEmu or ensure that cmder is started *before* you run your batch file.

Anyway, you have to enable beforementioned DefTerm feature.

Comment: I wasn't aware of ConEmu, and I think I'll do fine with it as I'm not a pro user of terminals. Thanks for the answer.